# add object to initial state in reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have my initial state:

```
export default function DrinkCalculator(state = initialState, action) {

  let payload = action.payload;
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_DRINKS_CALCULATOR:
    return [{
        ...state,
        ...payload
    }];
case ADD_DRINK:
  let newState= [Object.assign({},state)];
newState.push(action.payload);
return newState;
```

How can I add to my array to hold an array of objects? How would I need to change my reducer to add an object to an array, so I can store lots of entries rather than just one.

I would like my state to be:

```
[{
  drinkType: 5,
  drinkVolume: 4,
  drinkStrength: 5,
  drinkQuantity: 5,
  drinkStength: 5
},
{
  drinkType: 1,
  drinkVolume: 2,
  drinkStrength: 2,
  drinkQuantity: 5,
  drinkStength: 7
},
{
  drinkType: 3,
  drinkVolume: 5,
  drinkStrength: 2,
  drinkQuantity: 5,
  drinkStength: 5
},
{
  drinkType: 5,
  drinkVolume: 5,
  drinkStrength: 5,
  drinkQuantity: 5,
  drinkStength: 5
}
]
```

Update: I am getting nested objects copied into my state, I would like to get the top level properties and add them as an object to the array.

When I fire the action here:

```
onClick() {
const drinkQuantity = this.state.counter;

const drinks = this.props.DrinksCalculator;

if (!drinkQuantity) {
    this.props.dispatch(showError());
} else {
    this.props.dispatch(updateDrinksCalculator({drinkQuantity}));
// fire addDrink to copy drinks props in new object
    this.props.dispatch(addDrink( drinks ));

    this.props.router.push('/calc/5');
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `initialState` SHOULD NOT be changed, if you need a different structure then either change `initialState` to the array structure by default or use a different reducer.

Comment: I mean by default, updated question

Comment: Is the value of `action.payload` the `[{1:2,1:2}, {1:2,1:2,}, {1:2,1:2}, {1:2,1:2}]`? If so then you should do `return [...state, ...action.payload]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you want to add an new attribute to your state.

```
const initialState = {
  drinkType: null,
  drinkVolume: null,
  drinkStrength: null,
  drinkQuantity: null,
  drinkStength: null
};
const someReducer=(state=initialState,action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case "SOME_ACTION":{
    let newState= Object.assign({},state,{newAttribute:["value1","value2"]});
    return newState;
  }
}
```

This creates a state that has the newAttribute property in it.

Personally I like listing all the properties I'm going to use in the initialState. It makes easier to to people reading your code what properties they are going to be using and the data within.

**Another example of pushing an object into an array**

```
dispatch({
  type:"ADD_QUESTIONS",
  question:{
    drinkType: 5,
    drinkVolume: 4,
    drinkStrength: 5,
    drinkQuantity: 5,
    drinkStength: 5
  }
})

const initialState = {
  questions:[]
};

const someReducer=(state=initialState,action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case "ADD_QUESTIONS":{
    let newState= Object.assign({},state);
    newState.questions.push(action.question);
    return newState;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer, I need an array of objects, so I can map them to a table and display the data.

Comment: Are you calling an aysnc function multiple times and each time you want to add it to the list of objects in your reducer?

Comment: I have a reducer maintain the state for a click through questionaire, when its complete it pushes the completed state into an array.

Comment: Essential you can accomplish something like that with the example I have above above. I'll make an edit to reflect what it could look like for you